# Aura of Chaos and Alignment

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

Aura of Chaos, Perfect Order, Triumph, Tyranny: Can you use them as a crusader without being of the said alignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes.

All the following quotes are from the *Tome of Battle*:

> Most of these descriptors have no game effect by
>   themselves, but they govern how a maneuver interacts with
>   other maneuvers, powers, spells, or abilities.

This would indicate that, unless the stances in question say otherwise, the alignment descriptors have no game effect.

> In addition to meeting the class and level requirements before
>   you can learn a maneuver, you must meet a certain set of
>   requirements to be able to choose that maneuver as one you
>   know. Stances are considered maneuvers for the purpose of
>   meeting a prerequisite to learn a new maneuver.

We can assume from this that, unless alignment requirements are listed in the description of the stance, it is permissible to use them, regardless of your alignment.

From *every one of the four stances mentioned*:

> Level: Crusader 6
>
> Prerequisite: Two Devoted Spirit
>   maneuvers
>
> Initiation Action: 1 swift action
>
> Range: Personal
>
> Target: You
>
> Duration: Stance

Nowhere in the stances' descriptions or the prerequisites does it say you must be of a given alignment to use them.  While there *are* a set of strikes that have an alignment requirement, those strikes themselves are not a prereq for these stances, and thus their alignment requirements do not carry over.

Comment: I think it’d be fair to at least point out the high likelihood of this being in error, personally.

Comment: @KRyan I think your answer has that covered.  I'll be RAW, and you can be RAI, aye?

Comment: A question that merely covers RAW only to arrive at a counter-intuitive answer is not a good answer, imho.  I agree with KRyan about this, and would like to see a more comprehensive answer before removing my downvote.

Comment: @TheVagrantDog Considering you did the research to find this, my inclination would actually be to delete my answer in favor of yours—but right now it feels incomplete. (But that’s just me, and I don’t feel it earns my downvote by any means, personally.)

Comment: @godskook If we're going to talk intuition, I'd actually go the opposite way.  _Only_ those strikes have an alignment requirement, and the descriptors for those stances and strikes aren't on the list of descriptors that are supposed to be used for maneuvers.  Were I to play DM, I'd remove the alignment requirement and descriptors from both.

Comment: @TheVagrantDog We're not talking "preference" when we say the word "intuitive", we're talking "intuition about what was intended by these rules, based on our general experience with D&D 3.5".  Your preference to "strip the descriptors" is rather irrelevant to my point and my downvote.  (Although I don't downvote people who merely addendum their preferences to the end of an otherwise well-written answer)

Answer (score 3):

So the “aura” stances are a “cycle” of apparently-aligned maneuvers in the Devoted Spirit discipline. That discipline has one other similar cycle, of strikes. Those strikes include, in their prerequisites, the corresponding alignment along with the usual bit about requiring other Devoted Spirit maneuvers, e.g. *law bringer* has “**Prerequisite:** One Devoted Spirit maneuver, lawful alignment.”

The aura cycle is missing this prerequisite, but the general consensus seems to be that they should have it. Since *Tome of Battle*’s errata is actually an errata of *Complete Mage*, we are left without official word on the matter, but in all the games I’ve run, played, and discussed, those maneuvers were treated as aligned and no one brought up (or, likely, even *noticed*) that the maneuvers lack the prerequisite.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66303/discussion-on-answer-by-kryan-aura-of-chaos-and-alignment).